# Failling to install IIS on Windows 10 from Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible

Hey guys I am kind of new to Ansible, and I am currently trying to run a playbook that will install IIS.

I've already configure everything and got a message success when I try to ping to the host server (Windows 10 pro - host server)
I am running the playbook through my local computer with WSL (Windows subsystem linux) also a Windows 10 pro.

The script I am trying to run is:

```
---
- name: Install IIS
  hosts: win
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
   - win_feature:
       name: "Web-Server"
       state: present
       restart: yes
       include_sub_features: yes
       include_management_tools: yes
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 8
fatal: [MY IP SERVER-censored]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: The specified module 'ServerManager' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory."}
```

I have also tried to install Server manager to maybe trying to fix the problem but it didnt help to be honest.

As I said I am new to Ansible and still on learning terms.
I will appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ansible module "win_feature" only works on Windows servers.

The documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_feature_module.html) states: "This module uses the Add/Remove-WindowsFeature Cmdlets on Windows 2008 R2 and Install/Uninstall-WindowsFeature Cmdlets on Windows 2012, which are not available on client os machines."

Comment: So what can I use instead of the 'win_feature' for windows 10 vm host?
again, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Typing ["ansible install software windows" in my favorite search engine](https://www.qwant.com/?client=ext-firefox-sb&q=ansible+install+software+windows) gives a [quite interesting result as top answer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_package_module.html).

Comment: You can use Powershell (Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature) or cmd.exe (dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:feature_name). From Ansible you can use win_shell to accomplish the task.